# Error (segmentation fault core dumped) - List and struct pointer

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

Hi im a beginner in C programming; i'm trying to learn list and pointers to a struct. Here its my program to implement a list element after element  using pointers. Can somebody tell me why it gives me error segmentation fault core dumped?

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 

struct ListNode{ 
    int x; 
    struct ListNode* nextPtr; 
}; 

typedef struct ListNode ListNode; 
typedef ListNode* ListNodePtr; 

void insert(ListNodePtr* sPtr, int n); 

int main() 
{ 
    int f; 

    scanf("%d", &f); 
    ListNodePtr startPtr=NULL; 

    while(f!=-1) 
    { 
        insert(&startPtr, f); 

        scanf("%d",&f); 
        printf("/n"); 
    } 

    return 0; 
} 

void insert(ListNodePtr* sPtr, int n) 
{ 
    ListNodePtr newPtr; 

    newPtr=malloc(sizeof(ListNode)); 

    if(newPtr!=NULL) 
    { 
        newPtr->x=n; 
        newPtr->nextPtr=NULL; 
    } 

    ListNodePtr q,w; 

    q=*sPtr; 
    w=q->nextPtr; 

    while(w!=NULL) 
    { 
        q=w; 
        w=q->nextPtr; 
    } 

    w=newPtr; 
}
```

Comment: OP Why did you rollback the edit I made to make the code easier to read?

Comment: Because who really wants indentation and syntax highlighting?  :P

Comment: @MichaelDorgan pffftttt undoing a rollback to revert back to indentation and syntax highlighting.. :P nice job!

Comment: Yeah you know.  I was honestly waiting for OP to troll us both by rolling back again...

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean, thought OP trolled me by rolling back! xD

Comment: `typedef struct ListNode ListNode; 
typedef ListNode* ListNodePtr; ` You are confusing yourself.

Comment: `if(q=*sPtr){while(q->nextPtr!=NULL) 
    { 
        q=q->nextPtr; 
    } 

    q->nextPtr=newPtr; } else { *sPtr = newPtr; }`

Comment: Sorry, it was indentated then i copy and paste it here and it lost the indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time through your insert:

```
q=*sPtr; 
w=q->nextPtr;
```

`*sPtr` equals NULL.  You are dereferencing this which will cause a seg-fault on `q->nextPtr;`.